# Could not leave a discord guild

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to make my bot leave any guilds if the guilds size reaches 2 guilds

I tried everything from the Discord.js docs using leave()

```
// Here is my code on guildCreate.js event 
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
let guildArray = client.guilds.array();
module.exports = async function (msg,guild) {
 if(guildArray.size > 1) 
     await guild.leave()

};
```

It should works and leave the guild because the size is more than 2  guilds but it do nothing .

Comment: https://anidiots.guide/understanding/collections#custom-filtering you could modify this example to check if the guild has more than 1 person rather than 100.

Comment: thanks james but I'm not trying to make the bot leaves small or large guilds i want it to leave any guilds if the current guilds reaches two !

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this if I am right:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
    let guildnumber = client.guilds.size;
    while(guildnumber > 2 )
           {
            client.guilds.first().leave(); 
            guildnumber--;
            }
      });

client.log(token);
```

You can put it into ready and/or guildAdd as guildAdd only emits when your bot gets added to a guild and is online so you should check if your bot was added during it was offline

Comment: thanks PLASMA but it return error also using while will break everything down

Comment: also this should be on the guildCreate event not the ready event  right ?

Comment: using while on the ready event returns "FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory" shutdown

Comment: I updated the answer, it should explain everything now

Comment: returns : "FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory"